# PWA angular 17 specify which component to be cached

Tags: angular, typescript, progressive-web-apps, angular17, angular-pwa

I have a PWA angular 17 app. I know I could specify which files to be cached in `ngsw-config.json`. But the files should be the files after production build **in js or css**. This means all app components will be cached.

My question is:

Is there a way to specify which component **in development** to be cached only?
Is it convenient to cache all project files or I should choose some pages to be cached and work offline?